# php can't delete more than one row

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, sql-delete

I'm using a form with several checkboxes to make the user to select which rows he want to delete. The code to generate the form is this:

```
if ($busqueda!=""){
    $busca = mysqli_query($con, " SELECT id_user FROM usuarios WHERE
        id_user LIKE '%$busqueda%'");
    echo "<form action='borrar.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
    while ($array= mysqli_fetch_array($busca)){
        $user=makestring($array);
            echo"Usuario: <input type='checkbox' name='borrar_usuario' value='$user' />$user<br/>";
    }
    echo " <input type='submit' name='boton' value='eliminar' />";

   echo "</form>";
```

The code in borrar.php to delete the rows is this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["borrar_usuario"])) {
    foreach ($_POST as $valor){
    $del_user = $valor;
    $q_borrar = "delete from usuarios where id_user in ('$del_user')";
    mysqli_query($con, $q_borrar)or die(mysqli_error());

}
    //echo "usuario borrado";
    header('refresh: 3; url= exito.php');
}
```

The problem is that only deletes the first row selected and I do not know how to make it to delete all the options selected in the form. Any help, please?

Comment: OT: You should definitely escape your values.

Answer (score 1):

First change the name of your checkbox to include `[]`. Then when you submit the form php will convert it to an array.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='borrar_usuario[]' value='$user' />
```

Then in the php code that handles the form submission remove the loop and have this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["borrar_usuario"])) {
    $q_borrar = "delete from usuarios where id_user in ('" . implode("','", $_POST['borrar_usuario']) . "')";
    mysqli_query($con, $q_borrar)or die(mysqli_error());
    //echo "usuario borrado";
    header('refresh: 3; url= exito.php');
}
```

Comment: why turn it into an array then implode it ? If I'm not mistaken, the post value of fields having the same name will be a comma-separated list of the checked values...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work :

```
if(isset($_POST['borrar_usuario']))
{    
   $q_borrar = "delete from usuarios where id_user in ($_POST['borrar_usuario'])";
   mysqli_query($con, $q_borrar) or die(mysqli_error());
}
```